# Tesseract can't scan `Error:Only 1,2,4,5,6,8 bpp are supported:32`

Tags: conversion, ocr, tesseract-ocr

Even though I did `convert canvas.png -depth 8 canvas.tif` I am still seeing this error message:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine
check_legal_image_size:Error:Only 1,2,4,5,6,8 bpp are supported:32
Segmentation fault
```

Can someone explain why please?